# iOS5 ARC how to mark an iVar for retention?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a class that works by summing NSNumbers. One particular use of this class calls for only 2 types of numbers: 0 and 1. So I declared 2 instance variables in the .h file :

```
NSNumber* number1;
NSNumber* number0;
```

in the init method:

```
 number0 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:0];
 number1 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1];
```

When it's time to use the number a few minutes later the pointers are both nil. How can I persuade ARC to keep my variables alive for the life of the class?

Comment: Are you declaring number1 and number0 as instance variables of some class or are they declared at file level scope in the .h (i.e. global variables)?

Comment: Since ivars are strong references by default, you don't have to do anything else to keep the references alive.  Your error is not in those lines of code.  Show us where you allocate and initialize an instance of your class, and where you use that instance.

Comment: @Alex May I ask you why you keep those numbers as instance variables? If your intention is to cache them, note that NSNumber already has a cache for small integer numbers and, if iOS ever implements tagged pointers, they won’t even be full objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ensure that in your @property they are marked as strong in the @interface.  i.e.,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *number1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *number0;
```

don't forget @synthesize in your implementation.

In your init, you are correct in using not using the dot syntax for the property, but to get the benefit of the retain for the property you should try to use the dot syntax for properties else where.

Comment: Does this mean that from now on I have to use properties instead of iVars for the pointer types?

Comment: No I still have ivars.  Properies make it possible to use the dot syntax.  I.e self.number0=[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] will retain the autoreleased NSNumber.

Comment: @Alex - You can also use the `__strong` qualifier before the instance variables themselves, but by default they should be strong references. The code you describe above should still work when directly writing to the instance variables, so I think Rob is correct that something else is going on here.  You shouldn't need to use accessors to hold on to these numbers.  My money is that your init method either is not being called, or there is something else wrong with it.

Comment: As @BradLarson commented, properties may solve the issue but are not the right answer in this case.